# Nginx cannot load certificate in Windows

Tags: nginx

When I try to switch Nginx, I a mistake on the error.log

```
[emerg] 3620#11288: cannot load certificate "C:/Users/username/localhost.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('C:/Users/username/localhost.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

And I don't know how to solve it.

this is server in *nginx.conf*

```
 server {
       listen       443 ssl;
       server_name   platform.local.com;
       ssl_certificate      /Users/username/localhost.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key  /Users/tusername/localhost.key;

       location / {
                proxy_pass https://localhost:3001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                index  index.html index.htm;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the path /Users/username/ doesn't exist
you should replace username with your username

or the file localhost.crt doesn't exist in the path /Users/username/

Comment: I changed my name into username

Comment: How to check if localhost.crt doesn't exist in the path /Users/username/

Comment: you just open the folder /Users/username/

Comment: or execute this command and see what does it return. IF EXIST C:\Users\username\localhost.crt ECHO exists.

Comment: Yes, cannot find path. What should I do to create it?

Comment: do you have the file localhost.crt?

Comment: I do not know. I think, no

Comment: so of course it will not load a certificate that you don't have

Comment: Can you please write how to create it on Windows

Comment: follow this tutorial and use WSL: https://www.humankode.com/ssl/create-a-selfsigned-certificate-for-nginx-in-5-minutes